# What is A-movement ? Can I find a short essay that can explain it?

Tags: syntax, terminology, movement

I have been trying to get a summarized idea about A-movement.
I wish you could help me out with this . 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See [here for the distinction between](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_movement#A-movement_vs._A-bar_movement)  **A-movement** and **A'-movement** (=A-bar-movement).
In short, A-movement moves syntactic objects (words, phrases) into positions where grammatical functions can be assigned. See the examples and the explanations on the page referenced.
Please note that the concept of A-movement is taken for granted only in Government and Binding (GB) Theory, and related offshoots. The textbooks by Andrew Radford provide a very good introduction to the distinction you ask about.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input ...I have Radford's book, but I need something short and to the point.